Spring error: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
I'm trying to call one SDK API that is responsible for listing QRCode PIXs.
However, when I call the SDK function I get this error below:
java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:955)
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:759)
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:952)
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:759)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1690)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1599)
at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:531)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:307)

My code is set up like this:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    callApi();
}

private static void callApi() {
    try {
        final JSONObject credentials = new JSONObject();
        credentials.put("client_id", "client_id");
        credentials.put("client_secret", "client_secret");
        credentials.put("certificate", "certificate.p12");
        credentials.put("sandbox", "false");
        credentials.put("debug", "false");
        SDKPay sdkPay = new SDKPay(credentials);
        JSONObject response = sdkPay.call("listPix", new HashMap<>(), new JSONObject());
        System.out.print("PIX response: " + response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

One important note is if I call the function before spring starts and after spring starts it works correctly, the problem just happens when I call the function after spring starts. For example, the code below does not throw any error.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    callApi(); // If I call before spring starts it works correctly.
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    callApi(); // If I have already called before spring starts and I call again it works correctly too.
}

private static void callApi() {
    try {
        final JSONObject credentials = new JSONObject();
        credentials.put("client_id", "client_id");
        credentials.put("client_secret", "client_secret");
        credentials.put("certificate", "certificate.p12");
        credentials.put("sandbox", "false");
        credentials.put("debug", "false");
        SDKPay sdkPay = new SDKPay(credentials);
        JSONObject response = sdkPay.call("listPix", new HashMap<>(), new JSONObject());
        System.out.print("PIX response: " + response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

Does someone have any idea why it happens?

Smells of HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1690).  What is the .getInputStream0? And why does it refer to getInputStream0 twice? Did you hard code something you should input to spring to leave to do the job.

My problem is when I invoke the method sdkPay.call I get that error wherever I invoke.
The SDKPay is one library that is responsible for calling other external APIS to list keys.
I've just given the example above for being better to explain it.
